# Laravel Cache files losing permissions - Windows 10 IIS & Active Directory

Tags: laravel, windows, iis, caching

My problem is that when I use caching in Laravel with file driver, I occassionally lose permissions to the cache file. Permissions are set properly, parent folder does not lose any permissions, only the specific cache file. After restarting the machine, permissions are back and I can delete the file manually.

The "permission" error is like:
`file_put_contents(C:\inetpub\wwwroot\office_map_dev\storage\framework/cache/data/ca/0d/ca0d727b27eefcb8763203d9ad28f5a5eb29a85e): Failed to open stream: Permission denied`

Comment: Will this problem occur locally? or does it only appear when deployed on iis? This issue is caused by restricted permission. To resolve extend or change your permission to the folder.

Comment: @sawmu, it occurs being deployed on iis - the thing is that the permissions are set correctly, also to the cache file. After some iteration of cache clearing/writing it happens to lose permissions only on the file - the parent folder still has them.

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.

Comment: @samwu thank you for your help, it looks like there was a problem with locked file - after creating new one, the virtual machine's BitDefender was scanning and locking the file.
I've managed to make it work via checking if cache key exists before "forgetting" it.

Comment: Has your problem been solved?